# Just built a pc, and the chassis fans are struggling

Tags: motherboard, fan

I have an Antec Three Hundred Two case, which comes with 2 chassis fans.

I have an Asus Z87-A motherboard.

The PSU is a corsair 850w.

When I plugged it all together, and connected the case fans to the motherboard ports, they spin slowly and seem to struggle to start. In the BIOS, they are highlighted RED at ~300rpm. From what I can see, the settings are defaulted to a minimum of 600rpm which is presumably why they are red, to warn me they're going slower than they should be.

The only thing I can think of from googling is that the motherboard is 5V and the fans require 12V? The manual doesn't make any reference to the voltage or what fans are compatible with the board. I couldn't spot any settings to rectify this, and I tried putting the fans on full in the bios but it made no difference.

Any ideas? Should I be connecting them differently, is there perhaps a jumper setting, or should I be using some kind of adapter to connect them straight to the PSU?

Thanks

Comment: That dosen't quite sound right to me - most PC fans are 12V and I have *never* heard of them struggling.

Comment: @SLC - We need a picture of the fan connector in order to help.  There are several types of connectors for chassis fans, a low power connector for instance ( i.e. low speed ) will regulate the power and thus reduce the maxiumum speed.

Comment: Note that most of the time, the fans built into cases are of very poor quality. I wouldn't expect that from an Antec case though. do the fans still struggle after you boot into an OS? the BIOS can only load a limited set of power management drivers, so the OS does a lot of the work there.

Comment: I see, I'll have to post pictures when I get back from work. If I install speedfan will that let me attempt to crank them up? It might help to diagnose.

Comment: Please check your BIOS fan setting like in this link - Asus have flexible fan control settings: http://content.hwigroup.net/images/products_larges/186816/6/asus-z87-expert.jpg